# Multiple select dropdown list ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

When I create a post, I need a multi-select dropdown field, so I can select more than 1 category for 1 post.

I have created those entities: Post, Category, PostCategory

Do I need this `PostCategory` table? I mean, when I save a post, do I have to pass the data in this table in database?

Or is there any other way how I can create this dropdown? I am very confused

Comment: yes you have to create the PostCategory Table to connect with the Post and Category Table. and for drop down you could use <select multiple>. and as a another way you could use the javascript  libraries which offer more advanced components for handling multi-select inputs

Comment: so how do i add it to database? The post method of Create.